# Can run Flask application with `python` but not `uwsgi`?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up uWSGI to run a simple Flask application. I followed along with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04), which worked fine, but when implementing the same concepts on my project it didn't work.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/project
--/bin
----server.py
----wsgi.py
```

When I'm in the `/project` directory, the python command `python bin/wsgi.py` works fine. However, the uwsgi command `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http --wsgi-file bin/wsgi.py` doesn't. Here's `server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
# all my routes below...
```

Here's `wsgi.py`:

```
import os
from server import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    application.run(debug=True)
```

And here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
    from server import app
ImportError: No module named server
```

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `--wsgi-file bin/wsgi.py`, pass `--pythonpath=$(pwd)/bin` to uwsgi. Or make your app a package with `__init__.py` and use `from .server import ...` relative imports.

Comment: Thanks @drdaeman! Adding the `--pythonpath` argument worked. Reading the documentation now to figure out how it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why `python bin/mod.py` had worked?

   Because Python sets [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to include your `bin` directory, based on the directory `mod.py` (the command-line argument) was in:

   > As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

   You can check this out by adding `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` to your `wsgi.py`. The very first element would be your `bin` directory (full absolute path).
2. Why `uwsgi --wsgi-file bin/wsgi.py` hadn't worked?

   Because interpreter didn't knew where to find `server.py`. uWSGI hadn't took the path of `bin/wsgi.py` and haven't added it tothe embedded interpreter's `sys.path` (via `Py_SetProgramName` internal API call, `PySys_SetPath` or otherwise) - it had just initialized the interpreter and loaded the file.

   Basically, uWSGI is not a Python interpreter, it just hosts it, embedded.

   > If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.
3. Why `--pythonpath $(pwd)/bin` fixed things?

   Because you told Python interpreter where to look for imported modules. :-)